# Can't insert caption into image

Tags: captions

You can see live [example here](http://wpcandle.com/caption-test/).
When I add a caption into the image, it doesn't show at all!
  I've added the caption to the image as you can see in the next picture 
 
 [image: Here] 
 
 but it doesn't show as you see below 
 
 [image: here] 
 
 But when I click edit the picture icon as you see below 
 
 [image: here] 
 
 and fill in the caption field 
 
 [image: here] 
 
 the caption works! 
 
 [image: fine]

Why it's not working in the first case? I've disabled all plugins and no luck! I've tried the twenty fourteen theme, and no problem there, so the problem is in my theme only.
Can you please help!

Comment: What is the code that displays the image?

Comment: You can see it live here http://wpcandle.com/caption-test/

Comment: No, I can't. All I can see is the generated HTML. That is usually pretty useless. Where is the PHP source?

Comment: What PHP? I am not using a function to generate the caption, I am using the ordinary media uploader as you can see in the images above. I'm retrieving it with the_content() nothing unusual here :)

Comment: The Core functions are behaving as they are supposed to, as near as I can tell. If you want different behavior you will need to write code.

Comment: Try disabling all your plugins and see if it is still broken. Are you using a custom theme or a theme you found online?

Comment: @Howdy_McGee I tried disabling all my plugins with no luck. It's my custom theme, I'll try and remove all my custom functions, maybe one of them is the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it, the problem was a function I used to use and forgot about!

```
 add_filter( 'post_thumbnail_html', 'remove_thumbnail_dimensions', 10 );
 add_filter( 'image_send_to_editor', 'remove_thumbnail_dimensions', 10 );
 function remove_thumbnail_dimensions( $html ) {
     $html = preg_replace( '/(width|height)=\"\d*\"\s/', "", $html );
     return $html;
 }
```

I removed this function and everything is OK now.

Comment: Always great if you can solve your own problem. Don't forget to accept your answer as a solution. +1